# Does every model of $I\Delta_0$ has an end extension to a model of $I\Delta_0+\Omega_1$?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, open-problems, bounded-arithmetic

> Does every model of $I\Delta_0$ has an end extension to a model of $I\Delta_0+\Omega_1$?

In [End extensions of models of linearly bounded arithmetic](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007297000262) paper the author said this problem is open. I want know is there any progress on this problem?

Thanks.